# My site messes up when i change screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make my site responsive with only css I'm new to designing please help me, how can I make it responsive with only CSS?.

I tried using media query but it didn't work for me or maybe I don't know how to use it.

I am copying this Site: https://www.portfoliobox.net/

I know above site is made using bootstrap but I am doing it with html and css only.

Check out mine it messes up when screen size is change.
https://portfolioboxcopy.000webhostapp.com/

And tell me if i'm doing any mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: looks ok to me, what's wrong with it

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: without your codes we can't really help you.

Comment: Make a research on responsive website structure. Hope this will help.https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: I know you mention that you do not want to use Bootstrap but I would highly recommend it. Just a simple included reference to it and it would make the whole responsive design aspect of this a LOT easier. http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

A few tips on how you could improve your site, and make it responsive:

1. Avoid inline styles as they are hard to manage. Put your styles in a .css stylesheet and link to the stylesheet in a link tag somewhere before the closing `</head>` tag in your HTML document like so: 
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />`
2. To make your site responsive you should use percentage widths as often as you can and media queries to adapt your design. Media queries should be added as separate style rules, e.g:

```css
.bg1 {
  margin: -10px -8px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .bg1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

3. Avoid spaces in filenames like with your image "bg (1).jpg" as spaces are not allowed in file url's. Try something like "bg_1.jpg" instead.
4. Consider moving your current "header" element into a new wrapper element. This will make it easier to create a header area with a set height that can be changed with media queries. I recommend removing your "bg1" element and using the image in `background-image: url();` on the new wrapper element described above.